# Overlap div with div above

Tags: html, css, overlay

Ok, so I have been trying to make something like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaqqM.jpg)

However, whenever I change the top margin of "3" it also pulls up "2" to the same height. I wrapped "3" inside of "2" because I wanted the bottoms to line up.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.example {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.div3 {
  margin: -50px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

h1,p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <h1>
  Div 1
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <div class="div3">
   <h1>
   Div 3
   </h1>
   <p>
   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <h1>
  Div 4
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `top: -40px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -40px;` to `.div3`

Comment: Hi @UncaughtTypeError, although your answer may help in fixing the issue above I'd advise against using negative values wherever possible. It's against best practices.

Comment: I'm loath to use them as well - I only allow myself to make a few exceptions. But I would argue that it's only a bad thing if you abuse it for a quick-fix, not knowing *why* it's generally considered "against best practices".

Comment: Hi @Manu I'm just curious what the reasoning behind avoiding using negative values is. Also, is there a different solution to this that would be considered "better practice"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an effect of collapsing margins. I would simply do it the "other way around", position the element relative, and use a negative margin-bottom to have the outer div bottom end line up again.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.example {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.div3 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  margin: 0 auto -50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

h1,p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <h1>
  Div 1
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <div class="div3">
   <h1>
   Div 3
   </h1>
   <p>
   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <h1>
  Div 4
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to position div3 absolutely to div2 (which should be relative). You can then play with div3 independently without dragging div2 along the way.

Maybe something like this?

```
<div class="example">
  <h1>
  Div 1
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <h1>
  Hello
  </h1>
  <div class="div3">
   <h1>
   Div 3
   </h1>
   <p>
   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <h1>
  Div 4
  </h1>
</div>
```

And:

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.example {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.div2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -50px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h1,p {
  padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rdbjrqL3/

Answer (score 0):

Put `position: absolute` in **.div2** and `position:relative` in **.div3**

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.example {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  position: absolute;
}

.div3 {
  margin: -50px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  position:relative;
}

h1,p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <h1>
  Div 1
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <div class="div3">
   <h1>
   Div 3
   </h1>
   <p>
   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <h1>
  Div 4
  </h1>
</div>
```